# Users profile URL under root URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

The users' show action URL is "domain.com/users/(:id)". How can I change this into "domain.com/(:id)"?

(I use devise if it does make any difference.)

I added this in my routes but it doesn't work.

```
 get '(:username)' => 'users#show'
```

Couldn't figure out how is this possible in the Rails Routing [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

---

**Update**

I placed `get "/:username" => 'users#show'` at the bottom of my routes file. When I browse to `http://localhost:3000/testuser` I get this in my logs:

```
Started GET "/testuser" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-27 12:05:32 +0000
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"testuser"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

testuser does exist. But for some reason is nul and redirects to homepage. If I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/users/testuser` the user's show action loads up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
get "/:username" => 'users#show'
```

above root 'some_path'

**update**,

The route file match from up to bottom, let's say, you now have a route

```
 get "/search" => "controller#method"
```

if you put your get "/:username" before it, then your app may think you  are trying to find a user with username "search", so put the get "/:username" => 'users#show' at the bottom of your routes list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer some?

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the route `get "/:id" => 'users#show'` in my routes.rb file

Comment: This is what my answer is trying to say. The difference is in your controller, you want to use params[:id], but for my answer, you can use params[:username], you will get same result. because in your question, you use /:username, so I thought you would use params[:username] in your controller. After all, you got the key, congrats.